# How to enable tap-to-click in libinput on Ubuntu 19.04 x11 Unity

Tags: unity, xorg, touchpad

How to enable tap to click, double tap to right click and other such behaviours in libinput on Ubuntu 19.04 x11 Unity.
Enabing Tap to click in Mouse and Touchpad settings makes no difference.
The wanted behaviours work out of the box with xserver-xorg-input-synaptics installed.
I am using a Logitech Wireless Touchpad.

Answer (score 8):

This is a well known issue. You should ideally use `libinput`. Then you need to simply create a file and enable the options after targeting the right device.

```
 $ sudo su # Get root
 # touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf
 # vim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-touchpad.conf
```

Here you can now add additional options. A basic one would be:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
Driver "libinput"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  Option "Tapping" "on"
  Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
  Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
EndSection
```

Don't forget to reboot after this. For more options you should check the [man pages](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/libinput.4) for `libinput`. A better write-up [used to be here](https://ethans.me/codes/optimize-touchpad-performance-on-linux-en_US), and may [now be read here](https://ethans.me/posts/2019-03-10-optimizing-experience-of-using-touchpad-on-linux-with-xdotool-and-libinput-gestures/).

Comment: The provided link was 404d, should this be the right one now?.. https://ethans.me/posts/2019-03-10-optimizing-experience-of-using-touchpad-on-linux-with-xdotool-and-libinput-gestures/